# Marginal productivity of aggregate labor relation to wage

Tags: self-study

I know that $f'(l)=w$. But if i have that the aggregate production is $Y=AL^{1-α}$  with $L=N*l$ (The number of workers, $N$, multiplied by the labor force). So basically I want to find an expression for $w$ (the wage.).

---

**Full problem**:

Consider a one period economy, with aggregate technology given by: $Y=AL^{1-α}$ ,$0<α<1$. $L$ denotes the aggregate labor. The economy is integrated by $N$ identical agents, that offers labor force for a remuneration $w$. Also each person receives an Nth part of the earnings $π$ that generates the aggregate production. The objective of each agent is:

$\max \qquad γ\ln(1-l) + \ln(c)$.

$\text{subject to} \qquad c = wl + \frac{1}{Nπ(w)}$

Comment: What is $f(\cdot)$?

Comment: @Kun The exercise doesn't  gives you the production function a single one. Also it doesn't says anything about if the firms are all equal or  the number of  firms.

Comment: Do you guys think that something is missing in the exercise?

Comment: Giving us the entire text of the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Consider a one period economy, with aggregate technology given by: $Y=AL^{1-α}$ ,$0<α<1$. L denotates the aggregate labor. The economy is integrated by N identical agents, that offers labor force for a remuneration w. Also each person receives an Nth part of the earnings $π$ that generates the aggregate production. The objetive of each agent is: max $γln(1-l)+ln(c)$. subjet to $c=wl+1/Nπ(w)$

Comment: thats all the info that i have

Comment: Are you maximizing over $l$?

Answer (score 2):

So the firm's problem is, letting $L=Nl$

$\max_{L} Y-Lw\implies w=(1-\alpha)AL^{-\alpha}, \pi(w)=\alpha AL^{1-\alpha}$

Consumer's problem: substitute out c and only choose l, taking $\pi$ and $w$ as given

$\max_l u(l, wl+1/(N\pi))\implies -\gamma/(1-l)+w/(wl+1/(N\pi))=0$

Now substitute in the values for w and profit from the firm into the consumer's FOC and you will solve for labor supply (=labor demand as we are in eq) in terms of exogenous parameters ($\gamma, N,\alpha, A)$.